# Align Text in TextFlow to center - JavaFX FXML & CSS

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, javafx-css

At the moment I have a piece of text defined with Text in my FXML. It is also located inside a TextFlow which is inside a ScrollPane. I have tried aligning the text to center in the FXML itself and in css but still doesn't seen to be working. Here is the FXML

```
<ScrollPane fx:id = "scrollPane">
     <content>
         <TextFlow styleClass="txtFlow">
               <children>
                    <Text styleClass="h1" text="Title" textAlignment="CENTER"/>
                    <Text styleClass="h2" text="&#10;Subtitle"/>
              </children>
          </TextFlow>
    </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

And here is the CSS

```
.h1{
-fx-font-family: "Helvetica";
-fx-font-size: 50px;
-fx-fill: #147cb0;
-fx-underline: true;
-fx-alignment: center; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Uluk's answer, you can also achieve this using css by using the style on the `TextFlow`.

```
<TextFlow style="-fx-text-alignment: center;">
```

You can also get the desired effect by using a css file and a `styleclass` in it.

```
<TextFlow styleClass="txtFlow">
```

and on the css file as,

```
.txtFlow {
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To align texts in TextFlow use

```
<TextFlow textAlignment="CENTER"> ... </TextFlow>
```

To align the content of ScrollPane use

```
<ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" fitToWidth="true"> ... </ScrollPane>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to align only one text element to center?

Comment: @JoshBeaver, I don't think that is possible. Use another separate Text or TextFlow for title, and align it.